# Can't scroll on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I built my second responsive site and I'm having an issue with scrolling on mobile. I've only checked a blackberry z10 so far but I've checked more than one of them. I've checked it on web inspect through the phones browser and I've also deleted each element and still no scrolling. Maybe someone can see what I'm obviously missing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float: left;` on mobile screen for `.movies`. Then the height of the `<body>` tag will be calculated correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Removing the floats don't seem to help though. The changes are still live.

Comment: Please do delete the `float: left;` for me in the live demo.

Comment: I have. Except for the first 3 breakpoints I've removed float:left; from all the .movie classes.

Comment: It was the slider. I`ll give ya the answer.